# pip requirements.txt with alternative index

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I want to put all the requirements of a repoze Zope2 install in a pip [requirements file](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html#the-requirements-file-format). Most of the repoze packages don't seem to be on PyPi, but there's an alternative PyPi index for them [here](http://dist.repoze.org/zope2/2.10/simple/). But I can't figure out how to tell pip to use that index together with a requirements file. For single packages, it's easy

```
pip install zopelib -i http://dist.repoze.org/zope2/2.10/simple/
```

I tried the following

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -i http://dist.repoze.org/zope2/2.10/simple/
```

or in my requirements.txt all kind or permutations of these:

```
zopelib -i http://dist.repoze.org/zope2/2.10/simple/
zopelib --index http://dist.repoze.org/zope2/2.10/simple/
-i http://dist.repoze.org/zope2/2.10/simple/ zopelib
```

or (because the [documentation](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html#indexes-find-links) says "Note that all these options must be on a line of their own.")

```
--index http://dist.repoze.org/zope2/2.10/simple/
zopelib
```

So, what's the correct way of telling pip to use http://dist.repoze.org/zope2/2.10/simple/ as index?

Comment: You were very close in your last attempt; the full name of this option is `--index-url` not `--index`.

Comment: Docs (section `The following options are supported`): https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/?highlight=requirements.txt#requirements-file-format

Answer (score 150, accepted):

`requirements.txt`:

```
-i http://dist.repoze.org/zope2/2.10/simple
zopelib
```

Example:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
...
Successfully installed zopelib
```

Comment: For those curious, `-i` is short for `--index-url` if anyone prefers to be explicit.

Comment: For those who get a rejected connection due to security warning, you may need to add the domain as trusted to the command: 
`-i http://some.domain.org/simple --trusted-host some.domain.org`

Comment: If I have multiple packages from the same repo, do I have to include index URL for each package, or does the place where it is placed in file matters?

Comment: @kadamb: It's been awhile since I needed to use such syntax. My guess it is enough to include the option once and I don't know whether the order of options matters -- you could test it and post it as your own StackOverflow question & answer (or just leave a comment here, to help future visitors with a similar problem) [The docs might help](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/?highlight=requirements.txt#requirements-file-format)

Comment: any way to make this work with using the requirements file lines in setup.py?

Comment: @tkruse there is setuptools'  `dependency_links` but usually requirements in the setup.py are "abstract" and therefore such details should perhaps be reserved for "concrete" requirements used by pip.

Answer (score 74):

Add an extra index location to the requirements file just before the package/project name:

```
--extra-index-url <Extra URLs other than index-url>
<some_project_name>
```

Alternatively, you may use `-i` or `--index-url <Base URL of the Python Package Index>`.

Refer: [requirements file format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#requirements-file-format)

Comment: This works for me.  With `-i`, `pip install` is restricted to use only one source.

Comment: Use `--index-url` instead of `--extra-index-url` to prevent [dependency confusion attacks](https://medium.com/@alex.birsan/dependency-confusion-4a5d60fec610).

Comment: @animenon
As per the requirements format page ( https://web.archive.org/web/20220128085123/https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#global-options ), --extra-index-url is a global option which applies to the entire file. Your answer "Add an extra index location...just before the package/project name" implies a per package option.

Comment: @bfontaine How can I use `--index-url` for my custom packages but search on PyPI for everything else in a `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: @Rafael-WO IIRC you can’t do it in one command; you have to use two files: one with your custom requirements, and one with the others. For example: `pip --index-url … custom-requirements.txt` and then `pip install -r other-requirements.txt`.