# How to install python package with own pypi server?

Tags: python, installation, pip, pypi

I have created an own pypi server [ClueReleaseManager](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ClueReleaseManager) to 'mimic' the pypi server, followed the instructions and successfully uploaded a package to my own package server.

But how can I download and install the package from my server using `pip install`? I have configured the file `.pypirc` correctly, at least for the upload, and tried the following:

```
pip install MyPackage --no-index --find-links http://localhost:8081
pip install MyPackage --no-index --index-url http://localhost:8081
```

but in any case the package is not found. How can I do this, ideally with the name of the `index-server` already specified in `.pypirc`?

Comment: Adding `/simple` to any of the above examples does not solve the problem. The package cannot be found.

Comment: it should work e.g., see [pip requirements.txt with alternative index](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2477117/4279)