# How to make Python project depend on package in 3rd party website?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

How can I make my Python package depend on a remote wheel, not stored in a PyPI repository?

I'm developing a Python project on Windows for my organisation. I would like to be able to distribute this in a clean and easy way for others to install and use it.

One dependency of my project is the [MySQL-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python) package. A precompiled build of this package is not available in the PyPI repository (AFAIK). Compiling the package on Windows requires Visual Studio, which I can't assume will be available on all target computers.

So far, I've been using the pre-compiled wheel of this package kindly provided by Christoph Gohlke at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python.

I can manually install this package in my development virtualenv very easily by downloading [the package](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/zpx9vnfu/MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl), and running `pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`.

However, I can't figure out how to refer to this package in my project so that it will automatically downloaded and installed by anyone who uses my project.

Based on [this document](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/requirements/) it seems that setuptools' `install_requires` keyword is not appropriate:

> install_requires is a listing of “Abstract” requirements, i.e just
>   names and version restrictions that don’t determine where the
>   dependencies will be fulfilled from (i.e. from what index or source)

The same document seems to indicate that the `requirements.txt` file would be suitable to refer to alternate PyPI indices, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2477610/1506521). This shows that this `requirements.txt`:

```
-i http://dist.repoze.org/zope2/2.10/simple
zopelib
```

would be equivalent to the following command line `pip install zopelib --index-url http://dist.repoze.org/zope2/2.10/simple`. However, Christopher Gohlke's website is not a PyPI repo, so this doesn't work for me. It seems like the `--find-links` option would make sense, but when I try

```
pip install MySQL-python --find-links http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/zpx9vnfu/ --trusted-host www.lfd.uci.edu  --no-index
```

it doesn't work either:

```
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting MySQL-python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQL-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MySQL-python
```

If it's simply not possible to ask pip to look for a remote package, I've considered downloading the wheel file and checking it into my project's Git repository. This may have licensing concerns if the package is release publicly, but ought to be acceptable for an internal project (right?). However, while this command line works: `pip install MySQL-python --find-links .\wheelhouse\ --no-index`, I can't seem to incorporate the `--find-links` argument into my `requirements.txt` in the same way. This does not work:

```
--find-links .\wheelhouse
--no-index
MySQL-python==1.2.5
```

`pip install -r requirements.txt` results in:

```
You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting MySQL-python==1.2.5 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 3))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQL-python==1.2.5 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MySQL-python==1.2.5 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 3))
```

I've tried playing with the path the folder where the wheel has been downloaded: 
`file:///C:\Users\blaffoy\my_project\wheelhouse` and `C:\Users\blaffoy\my_project\wheelhouse` don't work either.

Another option that I haven't tried, though I think would work, would be to setup my own [devpi](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/) server. I'd like to avoid this if possible, because it seems to add an ongoing maintenance task for somebody in my organisation to look after it.

Any suggestions or ideas are welcome. This seems like it should be relatively simple, so I think I might be missing something obvious.

--- edit ---

I forgot to mention that I have tried setuptools' `dependency_links` keyword too. I couldn't get this to work either for a remote link to Christopher Gohlke's website or pointing to a local path. I also read somewhere that this is not considered good practise, and [may be deprecated](https://twitter.com/chris_zen/status/472420571100508160).

Comment: There is a `.exe` installer available at PyPi for this package.

Comment: Okay. How can I add a .exe installer to my project install script?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, what I mean is that I would like for other people to be able to download a single file representing my project (bdist, egg, wheel, whatever), and then run a single command (`pip install my_project.whl`, say) and then have a usable installation. Unless I've completely misunderstood, that's the point of a dependency management system like pip, right?

Comment: Okay, I figured out why `--find-links .\wheelhouse` didn't work in my `requirements.txt`. The backslash was being interpreted as an escape char, not a path separator. Replacing it with '\\' or '/' allows me to depend on a local package for the windows install. I suspect that this won't be portable to other OSes though. Maybe I'm dense, but I find Python packaging and dependencies so confusing and difficult that I missed what was probably a very simple problem.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, also IIRC an .exe installer won't install into a virtualenv, which makes development trickier.