# pip install with extra index url to requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I have following install comand for a package:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
```

and would need to add this to my requirements.txt file. I have done it by adding this to the end of the file:

```
-i https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
torch
torchvision 
torchaudio
```

after all the other requirements.
I do not have the means to test it right now, and would need to know if I have done it correctly as I never did it before.

Is this the proper way of adding it to the requirements.txt file?

If yes, adding other packages after these, for example numpy, will it be affected by the url? do I have to sort of "clear" the url, or is it simply added to the list of urls it searches in?

Any help appreciated

Comment: without knowing, my guess is it just adds the url to places pip can search for packages, I'm sure you could find that out in the docs somewhere https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/installation-report/

Comment: interstingly enough, I did try to do a `pip install -r requirements.txt` with your code there, and it DOES fail. Due to some package dependencies.. the -i part of it does work though.

Comment: might have to use something more recent than cu116 perhaps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip requirements.txt with alternative index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477117/pip-requirements-txt-with-alternative-index)

Comment: @Matthias yes, i googled, thats how i came up with the post in the first place. but since i cannot test it, I was searching for an answer from somebody with more experience. interenstigly it fails, that is not what I hoped. without the requirements, so running the install from the first line, it installs just fine, using cu116. the link you posted, basically says the same as my post, only difference that it works for him and not here apparently...

Comment: wow you are right, first line installs fine, the requirements.txt one has some problems resolving the dependencies or something

Comment: after I run the first line, and then uninstall with pip, then the requirements file does work, because pip uninstall doesn't uninstall the dependencies. But not in a fresh virtual environment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found the solution, the command you used and the `requirements.txt` file were NOT in fact the same. It works with a `requirements.txt` like this

```
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
torch
torchvision 
torchaudio
```

Turns out `-i` is not the same as `--extra-index-url`.

Docs: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/